# Mathemathica: How to plot error bar?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

This is my code

```
chiSVB1gExp = Import["Bi2212OPT_B1g_100K.read", "Table"]
chiSVB1g = Import["chiSV1g.dat", "Table"] ;
ListPlot[{chiSVB1g[[All, {1, 2}]], chiSVB1gExp[[All, {1, 2}]]}]
```

`chiSVB1gExp` and `chiSVB1g` are both three-columns file, but I want plot only the second one as a function of the first one. Now I want add an error bar only for `chiSVB1gExp`, It's says equal to 0.1 . I known that It's must be used `ErrorListPlot`.

Documentation center doesn't help me because It's makes example only for simple situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use zero errors for the set without errors :

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

(* initial data sets *)
data1 = {{1, 1, 10}, {2, 2, 20}} ;
data2 = {{3, 3, 30}, {4, 4, 40}} ;

(* transformed sets : data3 without errors *)
data3 = {#[[1 ;; 2]], ErrorBar[{0.0, 0.0}]} & /@ data1 ;
data4 = {#[[1 ;; 2]], ErrorBar[{-0.1, 0.1}]} & /@ data2 ;

ErrorListPlot[{data3, data4}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.01], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]